# How to load spring config xml ${ } values from spring boot application properties

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

Camel Spring Boot application version 2.20.1

How to load the application.properties values to spring config xml parameter on start up ?

For eg: few parameters are defined as follows :-

```
eas.ssl.key-store-type = JKS
eas.ssl.key-store-password = *****
eas.ssl.key-store = filelocation
```

Now the same need to be configured in Spring Config XML on startup as follows :

```
<sec:keyStore type="${eas.ssl.key-store-type}" password="${eas.ssl.key-store-password}" file="${eas.ssl.key-store}" />
```

In logs,I could see the properties from application properties are detected as expected

```
PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'eas.ssl.key-store-password'
```

However it looks like on the keys are not applied to config xml as values.
The errors log states:-

```
org.apache.cxf.transport.https.SSLUtils  : The key store password has not
been set via a system property or through configuration, reading data from 
the keystore will fail.
```

Comment: What is the `<sec:` namespace and where is it coming from.

Comment: The <sec> name space notation  is coming from this xmlns tag :

**xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"**

I guess this has got something to do with some version of camel cxf jars. But not sure, still researching.

Comment: I guess, the issue has nothing to do with property file loading. But got something to do with jdk version+cxf+camel jars versions am applying.

Am converting an existing jdk1.6 based camel app calling SOAP services using SSL handshake to a new Spring Boot based app;

It looks like cxf, camel jars used for 1.6 version does  not fit here. The error I got is -"**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol**" . This same soap call is working fine with same jks credentials in 1.6. My gut feeling the version of this jar is the culprit **[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]**

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my latest comment my primary issue was related to SSL HandshakeException (No appropraite protocol  found). And I was working with JDK 1.8.

Later I realized it was cipher filter "SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" was not supported with jdk 8. Once I changed to "TSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" all started working as expected.

A hint to solution got from this site :
http://www.ateam-oracle.com/tls-and-java/